# Typo3 Neos Responsive CSS Features

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, neoscms

Does Typo3 Neos have native support for responsive behaviour of elements? For example bootstrap like css grid classes (col-sm-?? or col-md-??) or can I define responsive visibility of specific elements via hidden-xs or visible-md etc. with Neos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Neos does support by default. But  need to include bootstrap library in header which is placed in Neos's own package Typo3. Twitter.Bootstrap. NeosDemoTypo3Org package has made use of inbuilt bootstrap too. I hope this is what you asked.